# Which version of CEF3 runtime is compatible with the TWAChromium?

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I have installed the current version of the [`TWAChromium`](https://bitbucket.org/WaspAce/wacef) component ([this commit](https://bitbucket.org/WaspAce/wacef/commits/4a5e2e979f867780d313d6cfe91bfe945abbe553)), but when I drop the component on a form and run the program I get the following error:

```
Exception EEXternalException in module libcef.dll
```

That seems to be due to an incompatible CEF3 runtime library that I've used. Sadly, there is no mention which version(s) of CEF3 runtime is compatible with that component. So my question is, which version(s) of CEF3 runtime is compatible with the current version of [`TWAChromium`](https://bitbucket.org/WaspAce/wacef) component ?

Comment: You're assuming the problem is an incompatible DLL, yet the error you're reporting is an exception in `libcef.dll`. This is not necessarily indicative of an incompatible DLL. I would suggest you try to isolate the problem further with a SSCCE and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi Andy, I had the program working using the TChromium. I am now trying to use the TWAChromium. the TWAChromium needs DLLs from the CEF library to  run, the problem is that the TWAChromium is not compatible with the latest version of this library and I do not seem able to find the right DLLs. So i am asking to people that is running a project using this component to kindly provide the DLLs. I know this is the problem as i had to fix the same problem when I was using the TChromium component.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all the people that tried to help. Especially TLama.

The reason for using the TWAChromium was to overcome the fact that i could not set the following javascipt flag:

```
--js-flags="--stack-size 2048"
```

to overcame a memory problem.

For whoever is interested the solution was to revert back to the TChromium component and to modify the javascript code that runs on my web web page. The code now uses objects that get created and destroyed all the time rather that use lots of temporary variables to manage complex calculations.

Feel free to post the DLLs that makes the TWAChromium work if you have got them as I would like to have the more recent version of the component working at same stage.